# Google apps script html template returning empty values

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to grab data from a spreadsheet, put it in an html template as a list, send it as an email, and attach it as a pdf. I'm getting hung up when it comes to displaying the html in the email.

Code.gs

```
function sendFormByEmail() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('formtemplate');
  var responses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var width = responses.getLastColumn();
  var headers = responses.getRange( 1, 1, 1, width ).getValues()[0];
  var data = responses.getRange( responses.getLastRow(), 1, 1, width ).getValues()[0];
  htmlBody.width = width;
  htmlBody.headers = headers;
  htmlBody.data = data;

  var subject = "Form Submission" ;

  // Email addresses
  var test = "email@gmail.com"; 
  var to = test; 

  // Grab template with data
  var html = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();
  Logger.log(html);

  // Convert HTML to PDF
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "text/html", "text.html");
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");

  // Send email and attachment
  MailApp.sendEmail( to, subject, '', {htmlBody: html, attachments: pdf}); 
};
```

formtemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul>
  <?
   // Loop through spreadsheet responses
  for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) { ?>
  <li><strong><? headers[i] ?></strong>: <? data[i] ?>
  <? } 
  ?>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried debugging and all the values appear in the html template, but when I check the html variable in Code.gs, I get empty html lists. included in the resulting html email. Any idea where I went wrong with this? My developer knowledge is fairly low, and I've cobbled this together from reading and looking at scripts online. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with [HTMLService's Scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates). When evaluating an HTMLTemplate you **must use [printing scriptlets:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets)** `<?= data[i] ?>` (notice the **=**) when you use variables. The code inside the printing scriptlets, "runs on the server before the page is served to the user."

formtemplate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul>
  <?
   // Loop through spreadsheet responses
  for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) { ?>
  <li><strong><?= headers[i] ?></strong>: <?= data[i] ?>
  <? } 
  ?>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more examples, see the 'Index.html' tab on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) in the documentation.

Comment: This did the trick. I'm kinda embarrassed I managed to overlook this. Thanks a lot for the help.